# JSprint Set Printer shared printer

Tags: javascript, firefox, printing, firefox-addon

How can I set the printer name in jsprint if it is a shared printer? Because if I just name it as is the printer name I got an error saying that it cannot see the printer.

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is from Dimitar Angelov, one of the creators of this wonderful add-on in Firefox that let you automatically print straight without the dialog box showing.

> "If you are using network printer, common mistake is wrong using of slashes.
>   For example if UNC name of your printer is \myserver\myprinter As javascript literal you must double slashes, because they are escape characters also.
>   The correct using of this UNC name will be:
>   var myprinter = '\\myserver\myprinter'; alert(myprinter); // to see if name is correct"
>   <

For further questions you can reach him on his email address:

mitko@edabg.com

Cheers!